# how to create static front page without using index.php

Tags: wordpress

WordPress:

1. I am trying to create a Static Home Page **without** using index.php
2. I have created a post page using index.php
3. I have created a front-page.php for the Home-Page.
4. I go to Setting>Reading>Front page: **Home** and then again 
   Setting>Reading>Posts page: (Name of Post page)
5. My Problem: Front-page showing "PostPage"

How to solve this issue?

Comment: question: why want to avoid using index.php as a home page? why not the contrary, set index.php as home page and a 'post-page.php' as post page? Aside to this, i guess the pages you are talking about are Wordpress pages (objects in the admin).. when you edit these pages, can't you choose the proper php file that is associated with this page?

Comment: at first I have tried this as you are saying. but in that case, post are not showing at the post page, posts are showing in home page

Comment: just a guess here, but your 2 pages may be both using the same template file (index.php), if you exchange the file contents, they will still use the same file, content will change for both. If not done, you have to give a template name to front-page.php, and select it in the corresponding page when editing in the admin. More details here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use

Comment: I am trying again from the beginning to create two new pages. -thank you

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: I tried and posts shows but the template header section is same to index.php/front-page.php. that is the problem occurs cyclic. I made a index.php and front-page.php with **same** codes, and created home-page using index.php. after that i created the post-page using using **post-page.php**. i added the pages to menu and went to settings>reading>..... but the header parts comes from index/front-page.php. could you please tell me, where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a template name for your front-page.php.

Add this lines before the get_header();

```
<?php
/* 
Template Name: homepage(or everything you want)
*/ 
?>
```

After that go to pages on wordpress and add to the page you want to set as frontpage the template homepage(or everything you want).

Go to Setting>Reading>Front page and set the page which has the template as front page.

Comment: Thank you for your helping mind but already I have tried this at the beginning.

Comment: What's written on your **thepageyouwantashomepage**.php?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer. I made a copy of index.php and renamed it home.php. And its working nice!